# Vaadin cannot find java class from my own external library

Tags: java, vaadin, libraries

I have a common-project, where most of my help-classes are stored, so that I can use them for almost every project I make.

Now, I have my Vaadin project, flow version 14, which I want to use it. However, when I add the jar file to the library, the classes in the library are not found.

I added the library-jar in this way: File > Project Structure > Libraries > + > Java > Found the jar > Ok > Apply > Ok.

The library is added to the external libraries.

When I add the library to other java/maven projects, I have no issues.

Here is an example code:

```
if (notify) Utility.sendToUser(LangOut.get("eTokenBad"));
```

Utility and LangOut are both found in the library. That line of code does not work in my Vaadin-project, but it works in any other project which uses the library too.

The error is listed as `cannot find symbol:224`. The line is 224.

I figure that there is an extra step for Vaadin to pick it up.

Comment: This should not have anything to do with Vaadin. Does this Vaadin project not use Maven? Are you using Jigsaw (Java 9 modules)?

Comment: Hi Oliver, it does use Maven. No Jigsaw as far as I am aware. How can I double-check? I believe it is using java 13.

Comment: Do you have a `module-info.java` file?

Comment: I do not seem to have one, no.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with Vaadin but how you make your dependencies available for Maven.

With Maven you have two options depending if you have access to a remote repository like Nexus, Artifactory, etc or not. Many organizations have this available on the Intranet. In that case you can **deploy** to that repository. Otherwise you can **install** to you local `~/.m2/repository` (Linux/Mac). Windows probably something like `C:\Users\[username]\.m2\repository`

**Local ~/.m2/repository** 
https://mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/

**Deploy to remote artifactory where you have access** 
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html

Comment: This [link](https://fabianlee.org/2017/02/20/maven-installing-a-3rd-party-jar-to-a-local-or-remote-repository/) shows both install then deploy with username/password.

Comment: Ok, so one step closer to my error. I can make it work with the Kaptcha in the first tutorial. But my own jar-file is wrong somehow. In the output for the mvn install for my own jar, it says that 'pom.xml not found in CommonMay-1.0.jar'. I suspect the error lies there? In my project, I do have a pom.xml file, so maybe the artifact production is wrong. What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: I now did it with 'mvn package' it removes the error with pom.xml, but it still does not find the classes in my project. So I still expect that I have made a mistake in creating the library.

Comment: I just followed the guide in another project (just a maven-project, no spring-boot or vaadin). In that project, the guide worked perfectly. So there is something specifically with this project that is stopping it from working.

Comment: It should not be any difference. Maven is still the same. Did you do an "install" or a "deploy"?

Comment: I did an install.